# Cake app - Newbie

Tags: cakephp

When I change some controller files in a cake app, does the web server automatically read the new info in those files or do I need to do something else? trying to replace an API key, but my changes seem to be ignored by the app.

Comment: Are you caching something?  You can try temporarily inserting Cache::clear() somewhere in your app to clear it out.

Comment: If you can explain your situation further in depth, for example, what you actually wanted to do, and what's your expected result.. etc, then we can help you.

Comment: The problem - an existing cake php app store locator uses Google Maps old API - we've tried swapping out the API key but receive 'over query limit' result.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're specifically caching it, there's nothing you need to do.